# Chest freezer failed to freeze after plugging it back in

Tags: repair

I unplugged my GE chest freezer for 3 months, When i plugged it back in the compressor runs but the freezer wont get cold.

The freezer sat in the same spot for 3 months and wouldn't get cold after it was plugged back up. 
The area that the compressor is in is clean and looks like new.

I never had a problem with it until i unplugged it.

Comment: Hi, and please check out some of the guidelines for this group.  In particular: what model freezer, how old is it , and how long did you wait to see if it's getting cold?   Good chance there's just a connection which started to leak once it warmed up, and a new fitting & a recharge could fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Worked when unplugged is all very well, but does not have any impact on what it does (n't do) NOW.

It's dead NOW, recycle it (or waste quite probably more than it's worth trying to get it repaired. Your call.)

Comment: This is speculative at best.

Comment: When a refrigeration appliance has a running compressor but does not get cold, it's dead, or in need of major repairs - which are typically not cost effective on consumer packaged appliance cooling systems. That's not "speculative" at all.

Comment: Ecnerwal,   why are you so certain that a simple leak repair and recharge won't take care of thngs?  Leave it up to the OP to decide whether (via estimates or local, skilled friend) which is more cost-effective

Comment: Because I have some idea of the cost of a chest freezer and the cost of getting a refrigeration mechanic to "roll truck" - plus the fact that many consumer packaged refrigeration devices require additional labor (which equals money and time) to install service fittings that were deliberately not provided as they were not really intended to be easily serviced. Throw in non-zero odds of an older, expensive, refrigerant and the math very rarely works out. Meanwhile, Carl, if you have a different answer, please put it in the answers space, not as comments here.

Comment: I don’t think this should have been down voted so I reversed one. 
I have a fridge in my office that was dead a 10$ crimp on port and 4 oz of 134a and it has worked for a couple of years, after I was sure it was worth it I did sweat a real port on it but I do this stuff. If a freezer won’t freeze a glass of water in 24 hours they are usually not worth fixing I do agree unless it is something like a sub zero that cost 10k then it would be worth it but I don’t think many chest freezers are high end but if it was a 1500$ model it might be worth a 150$ repair.

Answer (score 0):

With newer refrigerants (since Freon was banned), the seals on the moving parts in the compressor will sometimes dry out and leak if left off for long periods of time. It MIGHT work to recharge it and see if the seals swell up and seal again, but if the seals cracked, it will not, then you have wasted the money for the recharge. Most technicians will simply tell you that it isn't worth doing from a risk/reward standpoint.